# Xcode Projects: Is it possible to programmatically determine the path to a Library?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

I have an entry like this in my `pbxproj` file:

```
    146833FF1AC3E56700842450 /* React.xcodeproj */ = {isa = PBXFileReference; lastKnownFileType = "wrapper.pb-project"; name = React.xcodeproj; path = "../node_modules/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj"; sourceTree = "<group>"; };
```

The part of it I'm interested is this line:

```
path = "../node_modules/react-native/React/React.xcodeproj";
```

Is there a way to modify this so I could get the path to the `react-native` folder programatically?

Like, if this were a bash script, I could use an expansion like so:

```
"$(run-some-script)/React/React.xcodeproj"
```

I could make a script that the user could run to automatically update the paths in the `pbxproj` whenever they change, but I am curious if I could have a way to have Xcode run a command to get the path to this `React.xcodeproj` file whenever it is opened.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is no, but you can place other source code or a library files inside the toplevel xcode project directory and then reference these files as relative paths. That way, you can link to the project relative files and then update them and the xcode build will just make use of them. For example, you can include source code that is under a completely different git repo in a subdirectory, then you can update that code differently that the toplevel source, and yet still build the whole combined project together.